# Move lower index denoting p-norm norm lower than regular lower index

Tags: math-mode

I would like to have the lower index denoting the p-norm (0-"norm" in this case) slightly lower than a regular lower index, to achieve a look like this: [image]

This code:
`$[\lVert{}w_g\rVert{}_{0}$`

Produces this result: [image],
where 0 ang g are on the same level.

I've seen solutions where the position of the lower index is set for the whole document, however it's not compatible with my problem where I need one regular lower index and one lower lower index in the same equation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could encase the entire expression `\lVert w_g\rVert` in a pair of curly braces, i.e., write `${\lVert w_g\rVert}_{0}$` instead of `$\lVert w_g\rVert_{0}$`.

If you were to define a `\norm` macro with the help of the `mathtools`' package `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` macro, viz.,

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
```

the solution would be similar: you'd write `${\norm{w_g}}_0$` instead of `$\norm{w_g}_0$`.

[image]

The reason this approach works is as follows. First, it's helpful to know that the math "status" of `\rVert` is `math-close`, while the "status" of `{\lVert ... \rVert}` is `math-ord` ("ordinary"). Second, the (vertical) spacing rules for super- and sub-script terms that follow an object of type `math-ord` are more relaxed, i.e., allow for a greater vertical offset, than for objects of type `math-close`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\begin{document}
$\lVert w_g\rVert_{0}  \quad  \norm{w_g}_0 \qquad 
{\lVert w_g\rVert}_{0} \quad {\norm{w_g}}_0$
\end{document}
```